# Time Machine "waiting"

Tags: time-machine

I'm looking for a file on Time Machine and it says "waiting". It is a file in a recent backup. Why is time Machine "waiting"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have entered time machine via the top toolbar, you will receive the "Waiting" message (as shown in the image) when trying to navigate to an older backup. This is simply because time machine is waiting to load that backup.

[image: Waiting]

Be patient and wait for it to load

If it is taking a very long time to load, visit [This Link](http://pondini.org/TM/Troubleshooting.html) for troubleshooting

Comment: Pondini's site has been available since his death (I think in 2012), but went off-line recently. You can however find it using the Wayback Machine at http://web.archive.org.

Comment: Direct link to most recent copy in Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20170828102554/http://pondini.org/TM/Troubleshooting.html